# c++ Parsing FMOD bank files

Tags: c++, fmod

I'm looking to use the FMOD studio to generate sound effect configurations, and then parse the output bank files in my own engine, WITHOUT using the FMOD API.

Does anyone know if it can be done?

Also, FMOD generates many intermediate files with a xml content, could my objective be achieved by parsing these intermediate ".audiofile, .binfolder, etc.."?

Thank you for your help,

Jaime